# Use decorator on class with argument to restrict properties

Tags: typescript

As the question, would like to know if there's any approach that could have the class decorator restrict the decorated class properties based on the decorator argument in typescript.

---

code snippet

decorator:

```
type Exactly<T, U extends { [key in keyof T]: any }> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? any : never };

function DefinePolicy<K>(infer: K) {
  return function<TCtor extends Exactly<K, TCtor>>(cls: TCtor): TCtor {
    return cls;
  };
}
```

class:

```
export class ResouceOne {
  name: string;

  age: number;
}

@DefinePolicy(ResouceOne)
export class ResoureOnePolicy {
  name: 'foo';

  age: 20;

  incorrect: 'SHOULD GET ERROR';
}
```

type check:

```
type TypeCheck = ResoureOnePolicy extends Exactly<ResouceOne, ResoureOnePolicy>? true: false;

// type TypeCheck = false
```

So I did receive false from above type check, but seems like it doesn't really work in the inner function of decorator when there's unexpected property got defined in the decorated class.

How can we have the decorator capture the type error in the first? any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `<TCtor extends Exactly<K, TCtor>>` doesn't quite make sense, generic constraints aren't "checks" they are constraints, you can specify that type must be a subtype of something else, but not that it should fit some arbitrary condition.

So making it type safe in one way (requiring that every property from `infer` be present in `cls`) is not too difficult if focus the generics around the objects, not the classes. In the current code `K` and `TCtor` are classes so function that return some objects, but you are trying to check that these object have some type. So it would be easier to type those:

```js
// Accept class that instanciates object of type `K`
function DefinePolicy<K>(infer: new () => K) {
  return function<TCtor extends new () => K>(cls: TCtor): TCtor {
    return cls;
  };
}
```

Now this code will be an error for example:

```
@DefinePolicy(ResouceOne)
export class ResoureOnePolicy {
  name!: 'foo';
  // Oops no age
}
```

Getting rid of excess properties like `incorrect` in your snippet is trickier, you need to prevent function parameter `cls` to accept object of type `X` so that `cls` is assignable to `X`, in typescript everything is around `X` being assignable to `cls` and the other way is tricky. Here is one way. Firstly let's change inner function to also work with objects not classes:

```
function DefinePolicy<K>(infer: new () => K) {
  return function<TObj extends K>(cls: new () => TObj): new () => TObj {
    return cls;
  };
}
```

Basically what I want to do is after `TObj` has been determined check whether `K` is assignable to it (we know that `TObj` is assignable to `K` because of constraint, we only need to check the relation the other way): if it is, then leave this function as it is, if it is not, then change type of `cls` to `never` so that you aren't able to assign anything to it and it is an error. First I'll change `Exactly` type to this:

```
// Returns keys that are present in U but not in T
type ExcessKeys<T, U> = keyof { 
    [K in keyof U as K extends keyof T ? never : K]-?: true 
};
```

It should actually work withou "-?" but leaving it just to be sure in my abilities to use obscure features when unnecessary. Now the decorator becomes:

```
function DefinePolicy<K>(infer: new () => K) {
  return function<TObj extends K>(
    cls:
      // If there are no excess keys
      ExcessKeys<K, TObj> extends never ? 
        // Leave as is
        new () => TObj : 
        // Otherwise error
        never
    ): new () => TObj {
    return cls;
  };
}
```

[Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5ICIQMYHsBODi5QC8UAPACoBiArgHYbACWWtUEAHsBLQCZJQ16TFgD4AFMAQ4A5hGAAuKFToNmtAJTERUAG5ZGPKAB8lg1SwBQF0JCgBRdhggoA0hBBIKAGigBVbSQA1u5YAGZQAN5QFlCxUADaLlCMrMEgYX5QyFBJHFy8-GkZ5FAA-FC0EDoQOFCKLgC6ALSlisA41NAWAL4A3Nbg0ABKEGAIGIEUAZGJyakh4eQNiuSJDd1WoSrCrOihKRAAClhwjBggpC7iKaE1ipUA7lBimkTaLpoRMVA4ctQ4rC2QjUFAA8gAjABWbE43D4OXEGDgSEUDicrncnhcPnIEMh2jycP4lWqtXKj2er20uKhdQqVRq6nuECeLy0SjxkW+sV+wH+rCRSH6sT6PSsFg4YFwwCgSOQ-BGSCw-ycoMqXNitAQAFsIABCRRIdopaTCrKyA0Vaja8E1fobCwAAT2B2Op3OYkVypwqsq6gl7ClOBlcpQUC9KogaqOJzOIA1FR1+sUAHJQlgsCmzQgLYoAEwABntVmdEH2lTdcc9zm9vog-sl0tliDDEZ9UYrsfOAEYE1rdZa0xms98c8moIWzSlsDhfgxWlAUwBlAASoN8ABlUFAAOJ2Ep2IZDUFDEcO0vlmPukDVpWR6MNwNN0MKmv3zvXvN9pOD9OZqf0Lgc7AAuy5rpu257geR4nmeQA)

This isn't very consistent and I'm sure you will find some edge cases where this check will behave in a weird way, so maybe it's worth reconsidering what you are doing and leaving only the `TObj extends K` part, usually this is enough. Another problem with this approach is that the error is hard to trace: it just says `Type X is not assignable to type never` when the decorated class has some wrong property which is very unhelpful and hard to debug.